# Ubuntu - start a shell with multiple commands as a service

Tags: shell, ubuntu, service

Script location: `/usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh`

Script content (all 3 command are on the first line in the script):

```
sh /home/tb/Desktop/Installed/TeamCity/bin/runAll.sh start; sh /home/tb/Desktop/Installed/TeamCity/buildAgent_2/bin/agent.sh start; sh /home/tb/Desktop/Installed/TeamCity/buildAgent_3/bin/agent.sh start;
```

if I run this script manually in the terminal - everthing works as expected. But if I execute it from a .service it fails?

Service location: `/etc/systemd/system/TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service`

Service content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service that startup TeamCity and its 3 agents
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have also granted permissions like:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /etc/systemd/system/TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service
```

I have also run these commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service
```

I have also tried to add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line and just above the line `'ExecStart'` - but it doesn't change anything.

When I run the service with: systemctl start TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service I get the error below:

```
TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service - Service that startup TeamCity and its 3 agents
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-10 16:17:24 +04; 13s ago
  Process: 56412 ExecStart=/usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 56412 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 10 16:17:24 Monster systemd[1]: Started Service that startup TeamCity and its 3 agents.
Feb 10 16:17:24 Monster systemd[56412]: TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Feb 10 16:17:24 Monster systemd[56412]: TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh: Exec format error
Feb 10 16:17:24 Monster systemd[1]: TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 10 16:17:24 Monster systemd[1]: TeamCity_and_agents_startup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh
```

to this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/bin/Startup_tc_and_agents.sh
```

PS: `#!/bin/sh` was not necessary to include in the script in my case.

Comment: I just realized - That the code change above made the one error to disappear. But the service was still not starting - before I changed Type=simple to Type=forking! :-) It needed its own separate process to be executed inside.